# GraphQL resolver middleware for auth check

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I have a GraphQL API with mixed public and private queries and mutation. I'm looking for a way to check whether an operation requires the user to be authenticated and also a permission checker, so that the user can only modify his own data.

I noticed that the resolver function has a fourth argument, `info` that includes `path.key` which returns the name of the operation (documented [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers.html#Resolver-function-signature)).

My solution was to add a checker function inside every resolver, like so:

```
// modify user details
resolve: async (parent, args, { mongo: { User }, loggedUser }, info) => {
    // auth check
    authChecker(info.path.key, loggedUser, args.id);

  // continue resolving
},
```

And in another file:

```
function authChecker(operationName, loggedUser, userId) {
  if (PUBLIC_OPERATIONS.includes(operationName) {
    // public operation
    return true;
  } else {
    // private operation
    if (args.id) {
      // private operation that requires a permission check
      ...
    } else {
      // private operation that only requires user to be logged in
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The function either returns true or throws an error if conditions are not met.

I was wondering if this was an ok solution or if there was a way that this could be done with a middleware somehow so that I wouldn't have to repeat the code in every resolver. The problem is that I wouldn't have access to the operation name if I'd use a middleware. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/kriasoft/nodejs-api-starter/issues/78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing middleware should be possible, but would be painful because you would have to parse the query yourself. I think the cleanest way is to utilize a schema-level resolver, which is available with [graphql-tools](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools).

```
const {makeExecutableSchema, addSchemaLevelResolveFunction} = require('graphql-tools')

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers})
addSchemaLevelResolveFunction(schema, (root, args, context, info) => {
  // check info to see if query is private and throw if user isn't authenticated
})
// use the schema like normal
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({schema}))
```

The resolver doesn't need to return anything; it just needs to throw or return a rejected Promise when authentication fails. For more info about generating a schema with graphql-tools, check the docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema.html).

Comment: Awesome! I ended up using this to check if auth is needed for an operation. And I kept the permission checker inside each individual resolver. Thanks!